# Express middleware management

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logic, middleware

I have a little problem with express middleware management. Let me explain.

I'm working on the forgot password part of a 3-part mobile project:

1. Name and phone number are requested
2. Then, you're asked to enter the OTP received by sms and valid
3. And finally reset your password

So, the problem I'm having is that before resetting your password, you need to check that the OTP is created and valid, so you need a middleware that will check this. So the reset route will be like router.post('/resetPassword', authController.verifyOTP, authController.resetPassword);

But on the other hand, we also need a route that will verify the OTP and return a response on step 2 before moving on to step 3. Like router.post('/verifyOTP', authController.verifyOTP);

My concern is that I can't do next(); at the end of the verifyOTP function, otherwise the verifyOTP route won't work. How can I do this?

Here is my verifyOTP route handler:

```
exports.verifyOTP = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
 const { otp, email, phone } = req.body;
 let user;

 if (req.body.phone) user = await User.findOne({ phone: phone });
 if (req.body.email) user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

 if (!user || !user.otpCode) {
   return next(
    new AppError("No user found or you don't request OTP yet", 
    400),
   );
  }

 if (!(await bcrypt.compare(otp, user.otpCode)) || 
   user.otpCodeExpires < Date.now()) {
    return next(new AppError('OTP code is invalid or has expired', 400));
 }

 res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  message: 'valid OTP !',
 });
```

});

Comment: Just break your verify function into three parts.  A common portion that does the verification and returns the verification result (or a promise that resolves to the result), a route handler for the /verifyOTP route that calls the common part and a middleware handler for the `/resetPassword` route that also calls the common part.  For some unknown reason when people are writing route handlers or middleware they forget about factoring out common code into shared functions and using those shared functions from multiple routes/middleware.  This is just classic code factoring and code design.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. the portion that does the verification and returns the verification result is the /verifyOTP route. And what about the middleware handler for the /resetPassword? Can you show me by example please?

Comment: Clearly there exists a portion of the code that takes an OTP and a user as input and verifies it. That can be factored out into a common function that can be called by both handlers. This is simple code design of common, shared code. If you had included your original code, someone would have probably already written an answer that shows you how to do it in your code. But, instead you created a theoretical question which is 10x harder to answer completely. Questions about code here should always include your relevant code. You will get faster and more accurate answers if you include  your code.

Comment: As you say the verifyOTP function cannot serve as both middleware and as an endpoint handler.  One needs to call `next()` and the other needs to send a response.  So, make a common, shared function that does the verification and then a simple middleware that calls that function and then calls `next()` and a simple endpoint handler that calls the shared function and then sends a response.